# Drools HelloWorld sample application gives error

Tags: drools, rule-engine

When I first set up the sample hello world application I get errors in the `rules/sample.drl` files

The error is as follows:

```
Rule Compilation error Only a type can be imported. com.sample.DroolsTest.Message resolves to a package
Only a type can be imported. org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper resolves to a package
KnowledgeHelper cannot be resolved to a type
com.sample.DroolsTest.Message cannot be resolved to a type
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle cannot be resolved to a type
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle cannot be resolved to a type
java.lang.Exception cannot be resolved to a type
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.RuleContext cannot be resolved to a type
Message.GOODBYE cannot be resolved to a type
org.drools.core.util.bitmask.AllSetBitMask cannot be resolved to a type
com.sample.DroolsTest.Message cannot be resolved to a type
```

Also I fixed the error when I write `dialect "mvel"`
but for some reason I am not okay with this quick fix.

Am I missing some plugin or dependencies?
I am a newbie to drools rule engine and I followed all steps correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the most possible explanation is that you have missed some depedencies.

You need to include drools-core for example:

```
Only a type can be imported. org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper resolves to a package
```

suggests that Rules does not have access to KnowledgeHelper and tries to import it as a package.
Same thing happens with:

```
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.RuleContext
```

and kie-api depedency.

If you use Eclipse or some other IDE and started a new drools project then maybe drools library is not in build path.

Comment: Drools Library is there in the build path, also the dependencies for drools-core has been added to the pom.xml(if its the right way to do it). still i am getting the same compile error

Comment: If Drools Library is present you do not need to add the dependency drools-core since it already exits. Maybe there is some conflict with the library and your maven dependencies. 
Also since it is a compilation error and a hello world project, have you defined a drools runtime?

Comment: Yes i have defined a drools runtime , after writing the dialect the code compiles and gives a static binder log error/warning and executes the helloworld

Comment: The program executes without error right? and you do have messages printed in the console, don't you?
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Is that the error? If yes your program ideed executes (compiles and runs correctly) and you have simply not implemented an slf4j (logging) implementation.